# Как правильно удалять и сохранять файлы изображений в python flask

Tags: python, flask

Формируются 2 кортежа с именами файлов.
1 кортеж - имена файлов для удаления (получены из БД).
2 кортеж - имена файлов для сохранения (получены из формы).

Я пытаюсь так:

```
import os

old_name = (get_image_name.img_1, get_image_name.img_2, get_image_name.img_3)
new_name = (request.files['img_1'], request.files['img_2'], request.files['img_3'])

for i in range(3):
    os.remove(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + 'test_folder/', old_name[i]))
    new_name[i].save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + 'test_folder/', new_name[i].filename))
```

В таком виде, если требуется удалить 2 файла и при этом сохранить 3 файла, то 3й файл не сохраняется.
Хотя если требуется удалить 2 файла и сохранить 2, или удалить 3 файла и сохранить 2, то перезапись происходит корректно.

Как сделать так, что бы удалялось и сохранялось любое количество файлов?

Comment: А зачем Вы делаете все в одном цикле? Пустите цикл `for ... in ...` по первому кортежу и все удалите, а потом по второму кортежу и сохраните

Comment: Пробовал. В таком случае выполняется только 1й цикл. Либо записывает, либо удаляет, в зависимости от того, какой цикл будет первым.

Answer (score 0):

### Для того, чтобы перезаписать файл в python, вам не нужно его удалять, а потом создавать заново.

```py
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    f.write('This is new data, the old ones have been overwritten')
```

Если вам нужно перезаписать несколько файлов, то просто поместите конструкцию `with` в цикл `for`:

```py
file_names = ('a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt') # Кортеж с именами файлов
files_data = ( # Кортеж с данными
    'data inside the file a.txt',
    'data inside the file b.txt',
    'data inside the file c.txt'
)

for name, data for zip(file_names, files_data):
    with open(name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: Требуется удалять и сохранять изображения.

Comment: @GaloGramma, это нужно было указывать в своем вопросе сразу, а не после того как вам уже дали ответ.

Comment: Вопрос задан вполне точно - как удалять и сохранять, а не изменять содержимое файлов. Ответ дан на вопрос, который не задавался.

Comment: @GaloGramma, Вы изменили свой вопрос сразу после того, как написали комментарий.
Но в любом случае, вам нужно переформулировать свой вопрос, указать что вы пытались сделать, какой при этом получили трейсбек, и не обрезать исходники. Вот что такое например `request.files['img_1']`? Что он возвращает? Это какая-то либа, или это Ваш собственный класс?

Comment: request.files['img_1'] возвращает строку с названием файла (123.jpg). Трейсбека нет ибо код выполняется. Просто цикл выполняется на полностью.

Comment: @GaloGramma, так полный код можно? Я то разберусь, только не с чем разбираться

Comment: Код весь.. И он работает корректно, если в кортежах одинаковое количество элементов. Не получается заставить работать, если количество элементов разное.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136869/discussion-between-gnifajio-and-galo-gramma).